# Code reads the same file again and again instead of moving to the next file

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis

```
public void Main() 
{ 
    string sourceFolder = Dts.Variables["User::SourceFolder"].Value.ToString(); 
    string fileExtension = Dts.Variables["User::FileExtension"].Value.ToString();

    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(sourceFolder, "*" + fileExtension);

    // Dictionary to store the file name and its corresponding timestamp
    Dictionary<string, DateTime> fileTimestamps = new Dictionary<string, DateTime>();

    foreach (string file in files)
    {
        string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);
        string fileTimestamp = fileName.Substring(fileName.Length - 14); // Assuming the timestamp has a length of 14 characters

        DateTime timestamp;
        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(fileTimestamp, "yyyyMMddHHmmss", null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out timestamp))
        {
            fileTimestamps.Add(file, timestamp);
        }
   }
    // Get the latest file based on the timestamp
    string latestFile = fileTimestamps.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value).FirstOrDefault().Key;
    if (latestFile != null)
    {
        // Set the latest file path to a package variable
        Dts.Variables["User::LatestFile"].Value = latestFile;

        // Extract the table name from the filename
        string tableName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(latestFile);
        Dts.Variables["User::tableName"].Value = tableName;
        MessageBox.Show(tableName);
        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
    else
    {
        // No files found in the folder
        MessageBox.Show("No files found in the folder.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
    }
}
```

Could someone help me make change so it reads the next file. This program is to pick multiple files with the latest timestamp in a folder and load each file into its own table. I would need the table name and latest file as I have data flow tasks attached to the script task. All the files have different timestamps. From the script task, I feed the latest file to dataflow task and configured the file connection manager to read the table name from above. so it run dynamically. But it just keeps looping on one table.

Comment: You call FirstOrDefault, so you will only get one file?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are filling a dictionary with all of the files in the directory then you check for the latest file buy sorting the list by timestamp and selecting the one at the top. Since the timestamp on the files is granular to the second this should always return the same file.

If you want to use all the files with the same time stamp get the time stamp instead of the file name of the latest file  then just use a for each loop to process each file in the dictionary that has a matching timestamp while removing ones that have been processed from the dictionary. Something like this

```
// Get the latest timestamp
string latestTimestamp = fileTimestamps.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value).FirstOrDefault().Value;

if(fileTimestamps.Count <> 0)
{
    foreach (file in fileTimestamps )
    {
        if(file.Value = latestTimestamp) 
        {
            // Set the latest file path to a package variable
            Dts.Variables["User::LatestFile"].Value = file.key;

            // Extract the table name from the filename
            string tableName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.key);
            Dts.Variables["User::tableName"].Value = tableName;
            MessageBox.Show(tableName);
            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;

            fileTimestamps.remove(file)
        }
        else 
        {
            fileTimestamps.remove(file)
        }
    }
}
else
{
    // No files found in the folder
    MessageBox.Show("No files found in the folder.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
}
```

NOTE: you are currectly getting timestamps down to the second so this will only work for timestamps are the same. If you want all files from the same day for example you can get the time stamp only up to the days digit and fill the rest with zeros as you fill the dictionary. See below.

```
string fileTimestamp = fileName.Substring(fileName.Length - 14, fileName.Length -6) + '00000000'; // Assuming the timestamp has a length of 14 characters
```

Comment: I would need the table name and latest file as I have data flow tasks attached to the script task.

Comment: With the value of the dictionary being the timestamp is the key not still the name? Ive shown getting the filename differently here string tableName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.key);

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have this C# script that creates a dictionary with all the file names and the associated timestamp from the file name e.g. DailyFile_20230516001122, DailyFile_20230516011122, DailyFile_20230516021122, DailyFile_20230516031122, OtherFile_20230516001234, OtherFile_20230516021234, etc.

You then assign the DailyFile and 20230516031122 to SSIS Variables because it is the largest value.

What you're really after is the largest timestamp per base file name - DailyFile should be 20230516031122 and OtherFile should be 20230516021234.

What you need to do is not assign a single simple value, you need to assign the results to a SSIS Object type. That'll be an iterable value which you can then use as the source of a Foreach Loop Container - as a Variable enumerator. There, you'll extract the two items base file name and the timestamp and then do whatever you want with them.

Assuming all that is correct, here's how I'd do it.

## Set up

I generated some empty files to get some values out there

```
C:\>cd \ssisdata\input
C:\ssisdata\Input>mkdir so_76266788
C:\ssisdata\Input>cd so_76266788
C:\ssisdata\Input\so_76266788>echo > DailyFile_20230516001122.txt
C:\ssisdata\Input\so_76266788>echo > DailyFile_20230516011122.txt
C:\ssisdata\Input\so_76266788>echo > DailyFile_20230516021122.txt
C:\ssisdata\Input\so_76266788>echo > DailyFile_20230516031122.txt
C:\ssisdata\Input\so_76266788>echo > OtherFile_20230516001234.txt
C:\ssisdata\Input\so_76266788>echo > OtherFile_20230516021234.txt
```

[image]

## SSIS Variables

Beyond SourceFolder and FileExtension that you have defined

- User::rsMostRecent type Object This will be populated from a Script Task
- User::CurrentFile type String This will be used as the Foreach Enumerator. Initialize with a value of `C:\ssisdata\Input\so_76266788\Demo_20230516001122.txt`
- User::FileExtension type String Initialized with `.txt`
- User::SourceFolder type String Initialized with `C:\ssisdata\Input\so_76266788` NOTE, there is no trailing slash on that path.

The rest of these variables derive from those values. We'll do the derivation via the Expression language

- User::BaseFileName type String. Expression: `REPLACE( @[User::CurrentFile] ,  @[User::SourceFolder] +"\\", "" )`  If you have a trailing slash in SourceFolder, there is no need to concatenate the trailing slash here. Also note, to escape a back slash in an SSIS Expression string, you must double it up. The Value should show "Demo_20230516001122.txt" at this point
- User::FileNameWithoutExtension type String. Expression: `replace(@[User::BaseFileName], @[User::FileExtension], "")` The Value at this point should show "Demo_20230516001122"
- User::TableName type String. Expression: `LEFT( @[User::FileNameWithoutExtension], len(@[User::FileNameWithoutExtension])-14)` The Value at this point should show  "Demo_"

## SCR Populate rsMostRecent

The purpose of this task is to generate a list, not a dictionary, of the most recent version of a file. It will assign that to our variable rsMostRecent so be sure to list that as a ReadWrite variable and not a ReadOnly.

I am sure the LINQ can be optimized as I left some breadcrumbs in there in case you need to tweak it.

As the timestamp is already sortable, I didn't see a need to convert to an actual date but maybe you have a need.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace ST_d1ac15f4eb894b64a18ee3f1ea61ef1d
{
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute]
    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {
        public void Main()
        {
            List<string> mostRecentFiles = new List<string>();
            string sourceFolder = Dts.Variables["User::SourceFolder"].Value.ToString();
            string fileExtension = Dts.Variables["User::FileExtension"].Value.ToString();

            mostRecentFiles = GetMostRecentFiles(sourceFolder, fileExtension);
            Dts.Variables["User::rsMostRecent"].Value = mostRecentFiles;


            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }

        public static List<string> GetMostRecentFiles(string sourceFolder, string fileExtension)
        {
            List<string> mostRecentFiles = new List<string>();

            // This will be the fully qualified path, e.g. C:\ssisdata\Input\so_76266788\DailyFile_20230516001122.txt
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(sourceFolder, "*" + fileExtension);
            //var l = files.AsQueryable().Select(fn => new { FileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fn), TimeStamp = (String.Join(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fn).Reverse().Take(14)), new string() { "" }).Reverse().ToString() }).ToList();

            //.GroupBy(x => new { x.CurrentDay.Year, x.CurrentDay.Month })
            //.OrderBy(x => x.Key.Year)

            var l = files.AsQueryable()
                // fn takes the form of C:\ssisdata\Input\so_76266788\DailyFile_20230516001122.txt
                .Select(fn => new {
                    // DailyFile_yyyyMMddHHmmss
                    FileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fn),
                    // yyyyMMddHHmmss
                    TimeStamp = (Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fn)).Substring((Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fn).Length) - 14),
                    // DailyFile_ or OtherFile_
                    BaseFileName = (Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fn)).Substring(0, (Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fn).Length) - 14),
                    // FullyQualifiedName
                    FullyQualifiedName = fn
                })
                .GroupBy(g => g.BaseFileName)
                // Generate the survivor row
                .Select(g => new { FileName = g.Max(row => row.FileName), BaseFileName = g.Key, TimeStamp = g.Max(row => row.TimeStamp), FullyQualifiedName = g.Max(row => row.FullyQualifiedName) })
                .ToList();


            // TODO: What makes the most sense for your scenario?
            // Here I choose to return the fully qualified path as we can figure the rest out
            mostRecentFiles.AddRange(l.Select(x => x.FullyQualifiedName));

            return mostRecentFiles;
        }
        enum ScriptResults
        {
            Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
            Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
        };
    }
}
```

## FELC Variable Enum

This is a Foreach Loop Container configured to operate on the collection "Foreach From Variable Enumerator". As the Variable, choose User::rsMostRecent.

In the Variable Mappings tab, select User::CurrentFile as Index 0

## SCR Echo Back

This is a place holder script to show the current value of any read/write variable you selected in the first Script Task Editor screen. Longer writeup on my [blag](https://billfellows.blogspot.com/2016/04/biml-script-task-test-for-echo.html) In this case, I selected all the 7 variables from above.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ST_e8ec1fddbe33468eb86c3d4a6fe37e71
{
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute]
    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {
        public void Main()
        {
            bool fireAgain = false;

            foreach (Variable item in Dts.Variables)
            {
                Dts.Events.FireInformation(0, "SCR Echo Back", string.Format("{0}=>{1}", item.QualifiedName, item.Value), "", 0, ref fireAgain);
            }

            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }

        enum ScriptResults
        {
            Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
            Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
        };
    }
}
```

### Output

The Output tab/Progress window will show something like the following

```
SSIS package "C:\Users\bfellows\source\repos\SSIS_2022\SSIS_2022\SO_76266788.dtsx" starting.
Information: 0x0 at SCR Echo Values, SCR Echo Back: User::BaseFileName=>DailyFile_20230516031122.txt
Information: 0x0 at SCR Echo Values, SCR Echo Back: User::CurrentFile=>C:\ssisdata\Input\so_76266788\DailyFile_20230516031122.txt
Information: 0x0 at SCR Echo Values, SCR Echo Back: User::FileExtension=>.txt
Information: 0x0 at SCR Echo Values, SCR Echo Back: User::FileNameWithoutExtension=>DailyFile_20230516031122
Information: 0x0 at SCR Echo Values, SCR Echo Back: User::SourceFolder=>C:\ssisdata\Input\so_76266788
Information: 0x0 at SCR Echo Values, SCR Echo Back: User::TableName=>DailyFile_
Information: 0x0 at SCR Echo Values, SCR Echo Back: User::BaseFileName=>OtherFile_20230516021234.txt
Information: 0x0 at SCR Echo Values, SCR Echo Back: User::CurrentFile=>C:\ssisdata\Input\so_76266788\OtherFile_20230516021234.txt
Information: 0x0 at SCR Echo Values, SCR Echo Back: User::FileExtension=>.txt
Information: 0x0 at SCR Echo Values, SCR Echo Back: User::FileNameWithoutExtension=>OtherFile_20230516021234
Information: 0x0 at SCR Echo Values, SCR Echo Back: User::SourceFolder=>C:\ssisdata\Input\so_76266788
Information: 0x0 at SCR Echo Values, SCR Echo Back: User::TableName=>OtherFile_
SSIS package "C:\Users\bfellows\source\repos\SSIS_2022\SSIS_2022\SO_76266788.dtsx" finished: Success.
```